# React Native Picker: Set and Get different Picker Values

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-picker-select

I am working with React Native Picker and I have created two states: `userType` and `name`.

However, there are two `userType`: *Freelancer*, *Client*. There are also two `name` for each `userType`, and these are: *Freelancer 1*, *Freelancer 2*, and *Client 1*, *Client 2*.

Currently, I have two pickers. One has the `userType` and the other has `name`. Regardless of the `userType` selected, the 2nd picker shows all the `name` i.e Freelancer 1, Freelancer 2, Client 1, Client 2.

**But this is what I am trying to achieve:**

> *HOW TO*: Instead of showing all the `name`, I want to show specific `name` depending on the `userType` selected. For example: if `userType === Freelancer`, then `name` picker should display only `Freelancer 1, Freelancer 2`. And, if `userType === Client`, then `name` picker should display only `Client 1, Client 2`.

**Code snippet Provided Below:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userType: '',
        name: '',
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>User Type</Text>
                <View style={styles.pickerStyle}>
                    {<Picker
                        mode='dropdown'
                        selectedValue={this.state.userType}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                            this.setState({ userType: itemValue })
                        }>
                        <Picker.Item label="Select User Type" value="" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Freelancer" value="Freelancer" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Client" value="Client" />
                    </Picker>}
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>Name</Text>
                <View style={styles.pickerStyle}>
                    {<Picker
                        mode='dropdown'
                        selectedValue={this.state.name}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                            this.setState({ name: itemValue })
                        }>
                        <Picker.Item label="Please Select" value="" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Freelancer 1" value="Freelancer 1" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Freelancer 2" value="Freelancer 2" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Client 1" value="Client 1" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Client 2" value="Client 2" />
                    </Picker>}
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

**App Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have function that return usernames based on user type

```
renderUserNames() {
   if(this.state.userType=='Freelancer'){
    return [<Picker.Item label="Freelancer 1" value="Freelancer 1" />,
           <Picker.Item label="Freelancer 2" value="Freelancer 2" />]
   }else{
        return [<Picker.Item label="Client 1" value="Client 1" />,
         <Picker.Item label="Client 2" value="Client 2" />]
     }
}
```

then inside render function you can call i like

```
 render() {
let options=this.renderUserNames();
return (
    <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>User Type</Text>
            <View style={styles.pickerStyle}>
                {<Picker
                    mode='dropdown'
                    selectedValue={this.state.userType}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                        this.setState({ userType: itemValue })
                    }>
                    <Picker.Item label="Select User Type" value="" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Freelancer" value="Freelancer" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Client" value="Client" />
                </Picker>}
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>Name</Text>
            <View style={styles.pickerStyle}>
                {<Picker
                    mode='dropdown'
                    selectedValue={this.state.name}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                        this.setState({ name: itemValue })
                    }>
                    <Picker.Item label="Please Select" value="" />
                         {options}

                </Picker>}
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
);
 };
```

Comment: I just tried your method and it crashes my app as soon as I click on the `name` picker. [Here's the bug report](https://prnt.sc/qjwprk)

Comment: can you provide some kind of fiddle?

Comment: [Can you try this link?](https://snack.expo.io/H1UgtdxeU) I have commented out `{/*options*/}` on this.

Comment: @BeepBoop i have updated the answer and checked it,its worked

Comment: Also, on a side note, I am getting this warning on my console: `'Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'`

Comment: @BeepBoop  just add key prop with unique id to each Picker.item return from the renderUserNames